# Default case = last case

Tags: php

I want to make a switch and set the default case to be the last `valid` case.

```
$x = date("d"); // I get the current day
switch ($x) {
case 1:
    echo "bla bla bla 1"; break;
case 2:
    echo "bla bla bla 2"; break;
case 3:
    echo "bla bla bla 3"; break;
case 7:
    echo "bla bla bla 4"; break;
default:
    //Here I need to throw the last valid case.
```

For example if today is 5, my last valid option would be 3, so my default case should be case 3.

Is that possible using switch case? If not, is there any way to do it?
}

Comment: Are these days of the week?  You might be better off using constants instead of the number ( preferably class constants ), I would read a bit better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can stack them like this.,

```
switch ($x) {
case 1:
    echo "bla bla bla 1";
break;
case 2:
    echo "bla bla bla 2";
break;
case 3:
case 4:
case 5:
    echo "bla bla bla 3";
break;
case 6:
case 7:
    echo "bla bla bla 4";
break;
default:
} // don't forget this bracket its not in you original example.
```

As a side note I generally would avoid as you put "Here I need to throw the last valid case." in the default case, and use that for error checking the input, hard to say because I don't know where it comes from but, you can validate the input here if you know what that last one will be just put a case in for it, someone might think you forgot it at a latter time too.

Here is what I mean about a simple class,

```
class LottoWeeks {
   const Monday = 1;
   const Tuesday = 2;
  /// etc...
}
```

Then in your switch

```
switch ($x) {
case LottoWeeks::Monday:
    echo "bla bla bla 1";
break;
case LottoWeeks::Tuesday:
    echo "bla bla bla 2";
break;
//ect...
default:
   echo 'Invalid week'; //or other error message.
```

It reads a lot better.  You can look at it and don't have to think what day was 5 again etc.

Comment: Which is true, but why in the world would 3 be a valid case for 5?

Comment: Ask the OP "For example if today is 5, my last valid option would be 3,"

Comment: Sure, I understand that, just pondering here as to why that would be the case, makes no sense to me. I still +1'd ya anyway, pal.

Comment: I assuming these are days of the week, there are seven and the OP said  "For example if today is 5" maybe 4 and 5 are Saturday and Sunday and the OP don't work on weekends ... lol

Comment: Short version: I have a website with lottery results. There are 3 draws per week (mo, we and fr). If today is Saturday, all I need is the case of Friday. I don't want to make Saturday a particular case, I just want it to be a default case and that default case to be last valid case.

Comment: I would avoid using the default for this, id also make a simple class to hold the number values.

Comment: Hmmm...that should be an option too. In fact, this looks just fine :) I will do it this way tomorow morning. I would like to know also why do you think that isn't a good option to do it? In f Thank you for your help!

Comment: It's fine if you know there will never be a chance your day value would exceed 7, or be empty.  I'm just picky I guess, default is kind of a catch all, for values you don't know, its the else part of the if statement.  But for readability If there is only one option for the last one, I would just leave out the default even if I know the value will always be valid.